# Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

while starting producer at that moment i am getting this error

```
Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

broker.id=1 `broker.id=1
port =9020
advertised.host.name=10.44.72.204
advertised.port=9020`

Comment: Can you share the content of your `server.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me how many brokers are there in your cluster? Kafka broker rolling restart would fix this issue. If you still have issue then bring down all brokers once and start it again. Hope this would fix your issue.